# What happens to connection object after transaction.Commit or Rollback

Tags: c#, oracle

I've got a class called Databaseprovider and there I have a static OracleTransaction property called CurrentTransaction. Here's how I assign value to it:

```
        OracleConnection connection = ConnectionProvider.CreateConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();
        DatabaseProvider.CurrentTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

I've just noticed that after Commit or Rollback the connection property of my transactions gets set to null. Now I wonder what happens to the OracleConnection object I created before? Does it get Closed and disposed too, or it becomes a free, unreachable object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection remains open until the code has `.Close()`.

Instead of the above code, write the code with [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.

```
using (OracleConnection connection = ConnectionProvider.CreateConnection(conString))
{
   ....
}
```

Initialize the expensive objects when needed, dispose it off after the use.

Answer (score 2):

Use try catch finally block and close the connection explicitly in the finally block to release the connection.